# How to cast Array[Struct[String,String]] column type in Hive to Array[Map[String,String]]?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I've a column in a Hive table:

Column Name: Filters

Data Type:

```
 |-- filters: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
```

I want to get the value from this column by it's corresponding name.

What I did so far:

```
val sdf: DataFrame = sqlContext.sql("select * from <tablename> where id='12345'")

val sdfFilters = sdf.select("filters").rdd.map(r => r(0).asInstanceOf[Seq[(String,String)]]).collect()

Output: sdfFilters: Array[Seq[(String, String)]] = Array(WrappedArray([filter_RISKFACTOR,OIS.SPD.*], [filter_AGGCODE,IR]), WrappedArray([filter_AGGCODE,IR_]))
```

Note: Casting to Seq because WrappedArray to Map conversion is not possible.

What to do next?

Answer (score 1):

```
I want to get the value from this column by it's corresponding name.
```

If you want simple and reliable way to get all values  by name, you may flatten your table using *explode* and filter:

```
case class Data(name: String, value: String)
case class Filters(filters: Array[Data])

val df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(Seq(Filters(Array(Data("a", "b"), Data("a", "c"))), Filters(Array(Data("b", "c")))))
df.show()
+--------------+
|       filters|
+--------------+
|[[a,b], [a,c]]|
|       [[b,c]]|
+--------------+

df.withColumn("filter", explode($"filters"))
  .select($"filter.name" as "name", $"filter.value" as "value")
  .where($"name" === "a")
  .show()
+----+-----+
|name|value|
+----+-----+
|   a|    b|
|   a|    c|
+----+-----+
```

You can also collect your data any way you want:

```
val flatDf = df.withColumn("filter", explode($"filters")).select($"filter.name" as "name", $"filter.value" as "value")
flatDf.rdd.map(r => Array(r(0), r(1))).collect()
res0: Array[Array[Any]] = Array(Array(a, b), Array(a, c), Array(b, c))
flatDf.rdd.map(r => r(0) -> r(1)).groupByKey().collect() //not  the best idea, if you have many values per key
res1: Array[(Any, Iterable[Any])] = Array((b,CompactBuffer(c)), (a,CompactBuffer(b, c)))
```

If you want to cast `array[struct]` to `map[string, string]` for future saving to some storage - it's different story, and this case is better solved by UDF. Anyway, you have to avoid `collect()` as long as it possible to keep your code scalable.

Comment: I want to get the values b and c as a Sequence or Array of String not as Row object.